# Can we please make [css3] a synonym of [css]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

[css2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css2) is already a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/synonyms) of [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), why not [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3)?

---

[31,120 questions tagged css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3)

[18,732 of those are also tagged css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+css3)

***The facts are that 60% of questions with the tag [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) also have the tag [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).***

They are pretty much 1 in the same, with very slight differences like rounded corners, multiple backgrounds, box-shadows, etc.

Most people say css instead of css3, because most people see it as the same thing. Most people understand that the newer features of css3 don't work on older browsers. In most cases this is a non-issue since the site just won't look as *fancy*, since the generator just ignores the unknown style rules.

Comment: Do you have an actual reason? Something happening before is not a reason for that thing to happen again; especially when you have humans involved in the original decision...

Comment: CSS3 is *not* just CSS2 "with very slight differences", and it most certainly does not just make a site look "fancy".

Comment: This decision is being [re-discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385573/make-css3-a-synonym-of-css)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, please.

CSS2 is really a synonym of CSS, it has been released 2 years after CSS1, and nobody can really say they used CSS1 a day. And even if somebody can, it's so trivial in the CSS history and obsolete that we don't need a CSS1 tag.

As everybody used CSS2, we can consider it like a synonym of CSS, and not like a simple version. Have you ever heard someone say `I've got a CSS2 problem` ? Not me.

For CSS3, it's a bit different. There are major changes between CSS/CSS2 and CSS3. And sometimes you want to specify that your problem is related to these new features, as media queries, animations, etc. It's good to know that the question is not simply related to CSS.

Maybe a day, CSS4 will come. And maybe a day CSS3 will be totally obsolete. This day, it'll be the good time to ask this question. But I think the answer will be the same : major changes between CSS2 and CSS3 won't disappear.

Comment: CSS3 is just "any standard beyond CSS2", so a CSS4 wouldn't really make sense. I am a little concerned, though, because people seem to use the term CSS4 to mean *something*, and that might translate to a tag, but nobody really knows what it means (because it couldn't mean anything sensible in the first place).

Comment: @BoltClock CSS4 usually means just Selectors Level 4, http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/ , e.g. in contexts like http://css4-selectors.com/browser-selector-test/

Comment: @BoltClock welcome to my nightmare: I am against versioning everything, because then everything has to do with some version, when usually it isn't.

Comment: This decision is being [re-discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385573/make-css3-a-synonym-of-css)