# Make [html5] a synonym of [html]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Back in the day, it was useful to distinguish between [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) as HTML 5 was introducing new and interesting features to HTML, and different browsers had significantly different support for the new features.

Today, HTML is just HTML. The only tools which care about the differences are validators. Browsers just consume the tags and do the best they can with the elements they detect.

There is no point in distinguishing between versions of HTML and I get the impression that people are *very bad* at correctly tagging a question with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) or [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5).

If I look at [the list of questions for html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) right now, less than half the questions on the front page are about HTML 5 features.

Thus I propose [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) should be a synonym for [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html).

Comment: probably the same should be done for [tag:css3] and [tag:css] shortly

Comment: @TemaniAfif — I was pondering that, but thought I'd see how this proposal went down before investigating if that would be useful.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299916/when-is-the-css3-tag-appropriate

Comment: And most HTML5 *features* already have there [html5-feature] tags anyway.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, at least as I understand it, the WhatWG's "HTML Living Standard" has mostly won its war against the W3C's "HTML 5" and is the only standard that browser vendors now respect. The HTML 5.0 spec is a historical curiosity, and the HTML 5.x specs since are irrelevances. But most usage of the tag is *not* about any of those now-ignored W3C specs; instead, it's used on questions that are just about modern HTML, which in practice is not specced by the W3C and not called HTML 5. (The tag description even encourages this usage!) That seems am unnecessary source of confusion.

Comment: A hypothetical HTML 5 tag for questions specifically about the W3C's HTML 5.x specs might have some utility. Unfortunately, the `html5` tag ain't that and never will be, because we've given it an excerpt encouraging everyone to use it as *"an umbrella term for recent web technologies"*. Since the actually-respected modern HTML spec is just called HTML and not HTML 5, it does indeed seem appropriate to make our "recent web technologies" tag a synonym of `html`; I tentatively approve of this suggestion.

Comment: Looking at [tag:html5], why did [tag:time-tag] become a synoniem of [tag:html5]?

Comment: @kvantour Done by a CM 4 years ago. Since `<time>` is strictly an HTML5 thing, it makes some sense. We don't need a granular tag like that

Comment: I completely agree. I've given many HTML 5 answers to HTML-tagged questions without a HTML 5 tag, and likewise many CSS 3 answers to CSS-tagged questions without a CSS 3 tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually ask for a top user in the tag to review a synonym, if there are any, [but hey look who's asking](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html5/topusers)!
Given that [some more top users in the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385027/make-html5-a-synonym-of-html#comment697403_385027) were fine with this, I added [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) as a synonym for [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html).

Given that [xhtml5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml5) and [time-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-tag) were earlier merged with [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5), and the fact that we can't have synonym chains, I moved the synonyms to [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) instead.

I'll wait for a couple more weeks before merging the tags, just in case we face any issues with the synonym. (synonyms are reversible, merges are not)

Comment: As someone whose primary tag family for answers is in [tag:html] and [tag:css], I agree fully with the synonymization. There are no supported browsers to my knowledge that don't also fully (or as fully as any browser today does) support HTML5 as default, per se. Mark's comment above is also on point - the "living standard" has won the day and I think we're going to be living with version-agnostic "HTML" for quite some time. As for moving [xhtml] to [html], that's good, because there's never been an [xhtml5]. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/ for info on that.

Comment: Given the differences between XHTML and HTML, I do not agree with the synonymization of [xhtml5] to [html].

Comment: The synonym for [xhtml5] -> [html5] was proposed on 2013-10-10 by [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113772/paul-sweatte) and was approved some 2 months later via community vote. I just moved the synonym to the newer synonym, @MrLister.

Comment: Wait, you mean xhtml5 and html5 have been synonyms for six years and I never noticed? Oh dear. Sorry about that. I still disagree though.

Comment: @BhargavRao Is it realistic to reconsider relevant synonyms request for [tag:css3] to [tag:css]? It has been [raised 4 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266924) and the same synonym request could be approved for the same reasons HTML stuff was. This idea also has popularity in comments below this question.

Comment: @Vadim there is an answer that is against the merge, as well as the score of that post is in the negatives, so I don't think it would be a good idea to synonymize the tags against the wishes of the community. Feel free to post a new discussion, if you feel that the situation is different now.

Answer (score 15):

Initially I was against this. There are some major distinctions between prior HTML and HTML5 (I started in the dark ages of 4.01 and boy have we come a long way). But what got me was this

> There is no point in distinguishing between versions of HTML and I get the impression that people are very bad at correctly tagging a question with [html] or [html5].

He's right. The tag usage is all over the place, with [about 90k questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml5%5D+-%5Bhtml%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) tagged only [html5], when it should really have both that and [html].

For those unfamiliar, HTML5 [dropped the different DOCTYPE declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963135/what-is-the-correct-way-to-declare-an-html5-doctype) (you used to need to declare that so the browser would parse properly) and runs with a basic, versionless DOCTYPE. Heck, you could declare no DOCTYPE at all (not recommended) and start slapping HTML5 in and it would probably render properly. In practice, this means the browser gets to decide how best to run. So you can use *whatever tags or features the browser supports*, as opposed to declaring what type of HTML you're using.

As such, the [html] and [html5] ecosystems are being segmented for no good reason, and we're doing a disservice to users who are making poor tag choices. The synonym makes a lot of sense.

Comment: "you used to need to declare that so the browser would parse properly" — You still do. HTML 5 just gave up on using the Doctype to associate the document with a specific DTD and introduced a generic one designed to do nothing by trigger Standards Mode in browsers. Omitting it will trigger Quirks mode and cause things to render incorrectly (for backwards compatibility with bugs in IE 5ish).

Comment: @Quentin Edited in a clarification

Answer (score -26):

Agree, but then the questions about pre-5 HTML need to be back-retagged to [html-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-4).

Comment: Why? As OP wrote: *"Today, HTML is just HTML"*

Comment: Because HTML 5 and HTML 4 are still different languages...

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev — In practice, they aren't. That's the point.

Comment: @Quentin You'll rue the day once my HTML4 browser releases!

Comment: Only questions that are specifically about html4 would need this tag, but they are already using [tag:html4]...

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, but then they would tagged [html4] [html5] in the new situation, which would be a bit silly for questions about HTML4 only. I agree with ivan_pozdeev.

Comment: @MrLister No, they would be tagged `[html4] [html]`: the proposed synonym is `html5 -> html`, not `html -> html5`.

Comment: @MrLister my point was that [tag:html-4] is actually [tag:html4], and that it already serves the purpose this answer expects. The situation here is that [tag:html5] is unfortunately misused: The majority of the questions tagged [html5] **are not** about specificities of this version, unlike [html4]. That sucks, but being myself often around both tags, I can see very well why they should be synonymised: "HTML5" is a brand name and people use it because it still sounds cooler than "HTML". Now, the questions about  the specificities of HTML4 are already correctly tagged. No need to dig there.

Comment: This is a bad idea. It's useful for future readers of old questions to see answers indicating what the modern answer in the post-HTML-4 world is; almost all readers want to know what's correct *now*, not historical trivia about a two-decade-old spec. A mass retagging of all our front-end web development questions asked before a certain date (*when*, by the way? Many "HTML 5" features were widely implemented before the spec's release in 2014.) to imply that they are specifically about what a 1999 spec said and that answers based on modern spec are inappropriate would be madness and help nobody.