# Synonymize [xhtml5] and [xhtml]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

In the question [Make [html5] a synonym of [html]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385027) the tags [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) were merged.

That's OK, HTML5 has been the de facto standard for HTML since over half a decade now, so it's hard to argue with that.

However, in the process, I happened to notice that the tag [xhtml5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml5) was also merged with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), to which I must protest most strongly!

There are many differences between XHTML and HTML, even between XHTML5 and HTML5, so you can't really put them together in the same tag.

My suggestion is that we synonimize [xhtml5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml5) to [xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml) instead, which would make much more sense.

Comment: Finally, a question involving tags that doesn't come with a witty pun or a burnination request.

Comment: I wonder why `XHTML` even has versions, it's just strict `HTML`.

Comment: @Jeremy I don't think XML + HTML = XHTML. Not in terms of tags, at least. Somebody who is answering XML questions is not necessarily going to be able to answer an XHTML question. Somebody who answers HTML question is more likely to answer XHTML but there might be some specifics that elude them. Not sure if there are any questions right now that really need specific XHTML expertise that HTML doesn't cover but I still don't think XML people are interested in XHTML.

Comment: @Jeremy XML is different from HTML and XHTML. XML is a totally different languge, and XHTML is a strict version of HTML.

Comment: Frankly I'm surprised we have an XHTML5 tag to begin with.

Comment: @Jeremy - Oft repeated fallacies like "all XHTML is valid HTML" is precisely why XHTML needs to be kept separate. So that community members who know better can deal with XHTML targeted questions appropriately and accurately.

Comment: @LogicalBranch There _are_ differences in how different versions of XHTML are treated by the browsers, but that's beyond the scope of this question. I just don't want any tag about [XHTML*] to be a synonym of any [HTML*] tag; let's concentrate on that.

Comment: I agree the synonymisation of [xhtml5] to [html5] was a weird move, however, aren't there many differences between previous versions of *xhtml* and the latest *xhtml5* that do actually warrant it has its own tag? I agree to de-synonymize, however I'm not sure we should re-synonymize to [xhtml]: "xhtml5" doesn't suffer the same *brand-name* effect that makes [[html5\] an unfortunate synonym of [html\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385027/make-html5-a-synonym-of-html).

Comment: @Kaiido True; according to the WHATWG there is no such thing as XHTML5 (see also answer below); the proper name is "the XML syntax for HTML". But that would make for an awkward tag name, and everybody knows what "xhtml5" is, so we'll keep the tag. Now there are also differences between this syntax and earlier XHTML versions (like the lack of character entities), so we need to keep this as a separate version from, say [xhtml-1.1], but [xhtml5] as a synonym for [xhtml] is fine. We way need to adjust the tag wiki for [xhtml] a bit though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I was mentioning in a comment [on the linked meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385027/make-html5-a-synonym-of-html?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment697618_385140)

> The synonym for [xhtml5] -> [html5] was proposed on 2013-10-10 by [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113772/paul-sweatte) and was approved some 2 months later via community vote. I just moved the synonym to the newer synonym, @MrLister.

The synonym was there for some 6 years and nobody realized, which probably is a good argument to keep it at status quo. Also, the tag was remapped 20 times during that time, which also is indicative of the tag not being a very famous one.

However, the community has voted in favor of moving the synonym  to [xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml) instead, so, I removed the synonym from [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), and added it as a synonym to [xhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xhtml) instead.

Comment: Thank you. The fact that nobody noticed it was that way doesn't mean it was good! As you can see in the comments here, there are a lot of misunderstandings about there not being any difference between XHTML and HTML, so it's good to have that cleared up.

Comment: Yep, which is why I waited for a couple of days to see if there were any compelling arguments against moving the synonym.

Comment: FWIW, I did realize, but merging HTML5 with XHTML5 made a certain sense, since they share so much of the spec. But merging XHTML5 with HTML in general made much less sense when the XHTML tag continued to exist. Thank you for making the change.

Answer (score 5):

(Not advocating for a specific outcome, just an observation.) The term "XHTML" is no longer even used in the current version of the WHATWG HTML Living Standard. It's instead just referred to as the XML syntax for the HTML DOM. Here is a section relevant to this discussion, describing the relationship between HTML, XML, and XHTML.

> #### [WHATWG HTML Living Standard: Section 1.8: HTML vs XML Syntax](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#html-vs-xhtml)
>
> This specification defines an abstract language for describing documents and applications, and some APIs for interacting with in-memory representations of resources that use this language.
>
> The in-memory representation is known as "DOM HTML", or "the DOM" for short.
>
> There are various concrete syntaxes that can be used to transmit resources that use this abstract language, two of which are defined in this specification.
>
> The first such concrete syntax is the HTML syntax. This is the format suggested for most authors. If a document is transmitted with the `text/html` MIME type, then it will be processed as an HTML document by Web browsers. This specification defines the latest HTML syntax, known simply as "HTML".
>
> The second concrete syntax is XML. When a document is transmitted with an XML MIME type, such as `application/xhtml+xml`, then it is treated as an XML document by Web browsers, to be parsed by an XML processor. Authors are reminded that the processing for XML and HTML differs; in particular, even minor syntax errors will prevent a document labeled as XML from being rendered fully, whereas they would be ignored in the HTML syntax.
>
> > **NOTE:** The XML syntax for HTML was formerly referred to as "XHTML", but this specification does not use that term (among other reasons, because no such term is used for the HTML syntaxes of MathML and SVG).
>
> The DOM, the HTML syntax, and the XML syntax cannot all represent the same content. For example, namespaces cannot be represented using the HTML syntax, but they are supported in the DOM and in the XML syntax. Similarly, documents that use the `noscript` feature can be represented using the HTML syntax, but cannot be represented with the DOM or in the XML syntax. Comments that contain the string "`-->`" can only be represented in the DOM, not in the HTML and XML syntaxes.

It was still referred to as XHTML by the W3C HTML 5.2 Specification, but that specification is obsolete [and the next version will copy the WHATWG Standard](https://www.w3.org/blog/news/archives/7753).

Comment: Within the [introduction to HTML 5.2
W3C Recommendation, 14 December 2017](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.htm), section [1.6. HTML vs XML Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml) echos WHATWG's wording almost verbatim.

Comment: @DavidRR - No it doesn't. In your linked section, the term "XHTML" is used seven times and says 'This specification defines the latest version of the XHTML syntax, known simply as "XHTML"'.

Comment: @Alohci Indeed, while the wording by the two bodies is strikingly similar, there is a clear departure beginning in the fifth paragraph. There, WHATWG begins with: ***"The second concrete syntax is XML."*** While W3C begins with: ***"The second concrete syntax is the XHTML syntax, which is an application of XML."*** So, it is clear that W3C continues to embrace the term XHTML, while WHATWG does *not*.

Comment: @DavidRR This is part of the fallout from the ongoing feud between W3C and WHATWG. To summarize: while they both claim to be responsible for web standards like HTML, they have widely divergent ideas of how those standards should be developed.

Comment: This also results in inconsistencies. E.G. while [some pages on the W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#optional-tags) now say <caption>'s end tag is optional, [other pages](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/tabular-data.html#elementdef-caption) still say it isn't.

Comment: The WC3 spec is obsolete and irrelevant. The only ones who read or write it are the WC3 editors; everybody who actually develops browsers uses that WHATWG standard. W3C is doing a disservice by presenting their spec as still relevant because they're unwilling to accept that everyone got sick of their process and moved on.