# Is the overall quality of questions declining?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I've been on SO for a little over 7 years now, and admittedly focus on a fairly specific subset of content which may be tainting my view.

Over the last 6 months or so, despite some attempts to add more intelligent wizards/prompts for new users I've noticed more and more "do my homework for me" type questions creeping in, along with snarky "it's 2019 so why isn't there a better solution to X", or "I want to do X, tell me how and write the code for me".

While I don't mind flagging them to close and giving reasons and where possible pointers I can't help but feel it's making SO less of a great place to contribute, especially when the poster replies with some snark.

I'm not sure if the current concern about moderators bailing is going to impact the queue moderation and make the issues worse, or if this is something that can be addressed by further refinement of the initial handholding users get.

Oh, and while I'm at it (probably another topic) would be great if SO could prompt new users to come back and mark questions as answered to get them into good habits there as well ;)

Comment: Have you tried complaining on Twitter?

Comment: That's [nothing new](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow). But maybe, we finally have [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388313/experiment-ended-closing-and-reopening-happens-at-3-votes-for-the-next-30-day) to this problem. I'm waiting.

Comment: [html5][video] seems to be your niche.  Yes, something [did change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385027/make-html5-a-synonym-of-html) 6 months ago.  Ouch, that's an awful lot of cruft to dig through to find any question that matches your preferences.  Try to get ahead with a [custom query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html%20and%20video).

Comment: I wouldn't presume the presence of moderates and their activities relate to the quality and frequency of low quality questions being asked.

Comment: Not in my experience, I've had trouble finding questions worthwhile to answer for many years now. Most of what I see are questions that break every rule in the book, unanswerable no-research braindumps that took at most 2 minutes to type up or extreme duplicates that can be found by pasting the question title into google.

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: There are two factors that may make it **seem** like things are getting worse: one is that you yourself change, and (hopefully) are getting better at distinguishing between bad questions and good questions. This naturally also means you notice the bad questions more, and that recognition may seem like the bad questions are something new. They are not, you just weren't as sensitive to them before.

Comment: The other factor is that community curation, over time, removes loads of bad questions, so you'll naturally find more *recent* bad questions than *old* bad questions. It's not that (as a percentage of the daily question rate) there are more bad questions, it's just that the community model is quite good at sifting out the better questions out of the stream, given time.

Comment: Ever since the first question, _Where are my pants?_, question quality has steadily decreased

Comment: Yes... because SE's new mantra is to be "welcoming and inclusive"... and downvoting, flagging and closing bad questions made by lazy users is now seem as elitist and bigotry and generates bad press at tweeter...

Comment: @justAnotherUser... Yes, too many people go twitting on Tweeter.

Answer (score 10):

> Is the overall quality of questions declining?

Yes, and it would seem that it has for some time now.

> Over the last 6 months or so, despite some attempts to add more intelligent wizards/prompts for new users I've noticed more and more "do my homework for me" type questions creeping in, along with snarky "it's 2019 so why isn't there a better solution to X", or "I want to do X, tell me how and write the code for me".

You're not the only one to notice this.

In [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), it has become a recurring issue and one which is occurring more and more frequently to get questions that are just blatantly off-topic or those that don't provide the basic information needed to address their question.

> While I don't mind flagging them to close and giving reasons and where possible pointers I can't help but feel it's making SO less of a great place to contribute, especially when the poster replies with some snark.

Again, this is something I've noticed too.

My personal take on this is that SO reinforced the stereotypes that we, the community, are elitist or just downright toxic by committing to the "welcome wagon" and so people now take that and use it as ammunition against us when we close or down-vote.

> I'm not sure if the current concern about moderators bailing is going to impact the queue moderation and make the issues worse, or if this is something that can be addressed by further refinement of the initial handholding users get.

Yes, the "bailing" (though, that's not the word I'd use) mods will impact the moderation queues but more importantly, since the 3 close-vote experiment ended, I, and others, have felt the motivations to try and close questions plummet due to the effort it takes. It's further demotivating seeing objectively poor questions get sympathy up-votes.

But this isn't particularly surprising, SO has been heading in a `quantity > quality` direction for some time now. They just don't want to outright say it because I feel that they're afraid of losing their power-users which they need for the time being.

Comment: What evidence do you have for the quality declining? Right now this is a 'I noticed it too' post, hardly an answer. Have you got any reliable data?

Comment: I'm challenging this because *community curation clears out old dead wood*, so *new* dead wood is far more visible until time has passed. Don't underestimate the effects of having become more active over time, either, so you learn to recognize the dead wood better.

Comment: @MartijnPieters scattered across meta are various posts which provide evidence. I have no intention to rehash it but here is one regarding `[php]`: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334267/why-is-the-quality-of-php-questions-on-stack-overflow-in-decline

Comment: @Script47: so if this is a duplicate, you could have closed it as a duplicate. The post you link for **doesn't account for community curation either**, nor does it account for the fact that older posts have been around longer so have had more time to gain votes. The stats there are deeply flawed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I came across the link later by which point you'd already closed the question.

Comment: @Script47: there are several other issues with the stats there, but the fact that it doesn't understand the nature of how posts age is the biggest one. The comments on the post enumerate several others.