# Why I still see the score of merged tag in my profile?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, profile-page

It has been too long since [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3) was merged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) ([Make [css3] a synonym of [css]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385573/8620333)) but the score of the first tag is still visible on my profie:

[image]

Is this by design or a bug?

Considering the comments under [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385641/8620333) they should be transferred to the main tag:

> @TemaniAfif, the tag score will get transferred to the main tag. It's almost like 1 day or something, and then the tag badges recalc will happen the next day (shouldn't affect you). – Bhargav Rao♦ May 31 '19 at 16:53

Comment: The tags weren’t ever merged. Just synonymized. I can merge them now. I think Bhargav tends to hold off on merging to give us a chance to change our mind, since a tag merge is inherently destructive and can’t be undone. Probably been long enough now with no complaints, eh?

Comment: @CodyGray ah ok, so the same wasn't done for [tag:html5] then (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385140/8620333) ... well I guess there is no reason to wait more but I don't want to be the one who gives the *destructive* order :s ... I will try to bring more CSS users here to confirm.

Comment: Correct. [Showing off our fancy, relatively-new tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l27fS.png). This shows the synonym mapping [html5] to [html]. It shows that it was created by Bhargav Rao on May 17. It also gives us the option to *merge* the synonym tag into the master tag. (The "6971" shows how many times the system automatically corrected the synonym tag into the master tag, and "53m ago" shows when this was last done. So...the synonym is working!)

Comment: @CodyGray I guess the question may still apply but differently: why we still show score for synonym tag? the tag no more exist on its own since it will redirect to the main one.

Comment: It's still a separate tag, as far as the system is concerned, so the score is tracked, as are the number of questions with that tag. It's really more a UI bug, in that there's no way to display all of the questions with a tag that has been synonymized to another tag. Any attempt to list its questions will redirect to the master tag, of which it is a synonym. So...um, yeah, you've raised a whole thorny nest of issues with that last comment. :-) It's why we usually paper over this sort of thing by just merging the tags when we synonymize them.

Comment: Indeed, the system was very much designed for Bhargav to be the source of all confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tl;Dr, this is all by-design. Non merged tags do not add up on the tags page.

---

That day, Kaiido replied to my comment with a question:

> Ah then how come I still have my old different scores in html and html5? Cache?

after that I realized that I was wrong. I searched and then found some divine knowledge about the intricate system of tags documented by the Gods in some of the moderator only places.

Tags have two identifiers, "id" and "name".

Tag synonyms work on *name*.
Tag merges work on *id*.

A synonym does just the following:

1. replaces the tag to the one it was synonymized to, during post creation/updation.
2. redirects the tag pages to that of the tag to which it was synonymized.

and that's it. It does not update the old posts, it does not update the tag score on your page and so on. The synonymized tag is still present in the table with the original id. The addition is just that it gets a new "use this other name from now on" mark.

A merge does the following:

1. Updates all the old posts from the old tag to the new one.
2. Deletes the old tag entry and the old tag id from the table.

Now, after a tag merge, the tag scores are sync'd which is when you would see the two tags on your profile in the same position. This is where we get the famous tag synonym related rule:

*All tag synonyms would one day grow up to become tag merges*

Ideally, tag synonyms should be merged after a few days, which is exactly what I have been doing for all the synonyms that I have handled, [except two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLZuy.jpg), both of which you've linked in the question here.

The reason why I did not merge them was because they were huge. Merging is an irreversible operation which I did not want to do in haste. I wanted to wait for a few months before merging them and had set a date of 6 months. (however, this September, I was off from moderating and therefore I did not handle it)

Comment: So that really wasn't cache ;-)

Comment: It's cached, but the cache invalidates only when someone pushes the "merge" button ;p

Comment: I think you did the right thing by synonymizing first, specifically because of the irreversible nature of merging, as Cody mentioned. The tags are some of the most popular tags by volume. That said, I think it's been long enough to merge html5 into html and css3 into css now.

Comment: yes let's merge them, there is no reason to wait more.

Comment: Merged now. Oddly, it seems that the operation timed out without completing when I tried to do it from the list of tag synonyms, but when I used the "Merge tags" page, it worked OK.

Comment: @CodyGray, might wanna poke Shog in the mod room once before doing that merge. (headed to bed, else would have done it myself)

Comment: @BhargavRao The css3 tag just showed up in the new tags, with 1 question, tag id 142138. Are you able to fix that (re-merge or something) or poke Shog about it? Or should I just file that as a new bug report?

Comment: There's an option to create a synonym after merging @ErikA. I'm assuming that during this process, the original css3 tag was deleted when it was merged with css, and a new tag 142138 was created and synonymized to css. I don't remember the id of the original css3 tag, can you pick it up from SEDE/archive? It would be interesting to see the difference in the tag ids.

Comment: @BhargavRao The original ID for the css3 tag is 18929. I've never seen a merge creating a new tag before, but I don't monitor the new tags that tightly. I'm mainly surprised by the one question with the tag. Can't figure out which one it is until SEDE updates, I'm not that good with the API and it seems to redirect synonyms.

Comment: @ErikA, Thanks for finding that ID. I can confirm that the original css3 tag has been deleted, so my assumption seems to be holding correct. I am quite confident that we cannot figure out which question was that, because the tag is replaced on the original post by the CSS tag. For synonyms, we can still see the count on the main page which is the number of times it has been replaced.

Comment: Hmmm.... Perhaps I don't fully understand something, but I'll wait for SEDE to update so I can figure it out. I thought the x1 on the main site meant there was 1 question that still has the css3 tag and is just displayed as css because of the synonym, just like when the tags weren't merged yet. And since they are merged, that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Actually yeah, @ErikA, my assumption might be wrong. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocXmt.png just shows the tag, even though there have been a few renames. Lemme check the merge page again.

Comment: Yup @Erik, it allowed me to merge the tags again. Given that the new question came in between Cody's comment and my comment (19:59Z), I'm now guessing that a race condition might have occurred. Something like, tag deleted first, and then posts updated to the new tag, (somewhere here the new post with the new tag was created), then new synonym added. It's all a black box to me too.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it, I don't like stuff that shouldn't be able to exist hanging around :)

Comment: Must have been a race condition. The merge took a *very* long time, and actually timed out multiple times before it finally went through. Doesn't particularly surprise me that some weirdness snuck in during that time. Glad it's all sorted now.