# Is the process of making two tags synonyms reversible?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process, tag-wiki

In the past, the tag wikis of [memory-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-model) and [memory-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-order) didn't explain when to use each tag. About a year ago, I changed the tag wikis to give a clear and different purpose for each of these already existing tags. In particular, I clarified that [memory-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-model) is for questions on memory models at the programming language level above the ISA level and that [memory-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-order) is for questions on memory models at the ISA levels or implementation details at the microarchitecture level.

The tag wiki of [memory-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-model) that I've written is still there. I've also mentioned there that other tags, such as [memory-fences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-fences) and [memory-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-order), are related but different (as the respective tag wikis explain). The scope of [memory-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-model) (and [memory-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-order)) includes [memory-fences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-fences), which is much more specific. Another related tag is [memory-fences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-fences), which is a synonym to [memory-barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-barriers), as it should be.

Recently, when I was trying to retag [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60081485/what-happens-to-expected-memory-semantics-such-as-read-after-write-when-a-thre) question with [memory-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-order), which is the only suitable tag among all of these tags in that case,  I noticed that [memory-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-order) has become a synonym to [memory-fences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-fences) (which is a synonym to [memory-barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-barriers)). Notice how [memory-barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-barriers) is shown under the question. But the question is not really about memory barriers in particular, so the tag name is not suitable.

Even if we want to consider [memory-fences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-fences) and [memory-barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-barriers) redundant, the more general tag [memory-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-order) is the one that should be shown under the question, not [memory-barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-barriers), which is more specific.

This problem has motivated me to ask the following question: is it possible to reverse the process of making two tags synonyms? If not, can [memory-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-order) be shown instead of [memory-barriers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-barriers)?

Note that I didn't create any of these tags, in case anyone is wondering. Although I thought everything was OK before making [memory-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-order) a synonym.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392753/8620333 and I suppose they are already merged. If so then it's irreverisble

Comment: If you would have access to an older version of the database or data dump or even from the internet archive of the present questions with these tags you might be able to achieve something. The company should have that in any case.